# Keyboard spell checker ruin layout

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm having the following UI bug in HTC One x, I'm using a dialog with EditText inside.
The bug is that when the user writes something, the spell checker shows suggestions, and the user presses "post", the spell checker is disappearing and the layout doesn't stretch itself correct, and the layout looks weird after it.

Take a look:
[image]

The solutions that I tried was to set the layout to height FILL_PARENT but it didn't do anything.

also a call to invalidate() was useless.

Bad solution is to disable the spell checker but this is my last option.

I know that for example in Google talk they solved this issue somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a walk around but still good enough for me:

I disabled the suggestions of the keyboard and that do the trick.

Here is the code:

```
msgEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```